# Why isn't Cucumber considered as a testing tool?

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd

I'm new to Cucumber, and I'm trying to understand the tool. While reading [the documentation](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/overview/), I found that it is defined shortly as **"a tool that supports BDD"**:

> Cucumber is a tool that supports Behaviour-Driven Development(BDD).

Also it is described as a "validation tool":

> Cucumber reads executable specifications written in plain text and validates that the software does what those specifications say.

In the other side, I noticed the excessive use of the word **"test"** on the [10-minute tutorial](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).

AFAIK, what does this tool is agile testing, since it is used massively in e2e testing (test basis = Gherkin feature specs + step definitions). However, [the blog](https://cucumber.io/blog/where_should_you_use_bdd/) says something different:

> Finally, remember that Cucumber is **not a testing tool**. It is a tool for capturing common understanding on how a system should work. A tool that allows you, but doesn't require you, to automate the verification of the behaviour of your system if you find it useful.

Now if this tool is not really about testing, then what use is it intended for?

Comment: Cucmber is used to specify test cases with input and expected result. It doesn't execute the tests, or interact with the software under test directly. For that you use a tool that drives a browser like Selenium for example. Then you have something like JUnit inbetween that reads Cucumber specs, and lets Selenium drive the browser.

Comment: that is a longer story. To clarify I can recommend the "BDD in Action" book. It does a very nice explanation of the concepts and motivations behind BDD and what sort of tests on what levels of abstractions you target. I think if you just look at this as a tool you will miss out on the concepts that BDD requires to be very useful - and not just some testing tool.

Comment: @wemu I know that, *as a tool*, Cucumber only validates the BDD test specs. And if it does only so, why can't we call it a testing tool?

Comment: @wemu or testing tool for BDD?

Comment: @ou_ryperd Cucumber requires the feature file (Gherkin) and the step definitions (test cases: up to developer to implement them). The tests should be run by invoking the tool directly, it will read the user input so that the tests get executed.

Comment: @Kais not sure I understand what yo are getting at. Think of it this way: development teams use word processors. Does it assist with development ? Yes (for e.g. specifying things). Is it a **development** tool ? No.

Comment: well not so new then are we? In that sense cucumber is a tool to execute specifications (that hopefully contain examples) based on a defined language that hopefully describe behaviour allowing to run that specification against your code through step definitions you provide. Sort of that slice of tests. What you use it for is up to you. Or what test slice you target with it. You might only use it for generating documentation for specified behaviour not running tests at all. So its a broad segment of possibilities.

Comment: @wemu Is there any guide or example on how to generate docs using Cucumber?

Comment: not that I know of. Cucumber supports generating html pages out of the box. there are also tools on top of it like: http://www.thucydides.info/ that generate reports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### **TL;DR**

Cucumber is a BDD framework. Its main components are:

1. [Gherkin](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/): a ubiquitous language used as communication tool than
   anything, and can be used as a springboard for collaboration. It
   helps manage the expectations of the business, and if everyone can
   see the changes that you are making in a digestible format, they'll
   hopefully get less frustrated with the development teams, but also
   you can use it to speed up the reaction time of your team if there
   are bugs, by writing the tests that cucumber wraps with the mindset
   that someone is going to have to come back and debug it at some
   point.
2. [CLI implementation](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/) (or the CLI): a test runner based on
   Gherkin. It is developed by volunteers who are all donating part of
   their spare time. Every implementation is specific to a programming
   language supporting a production code that is ready for test. It is
   considered as the concrete tool / utility.

### The Long Version

The intended use of Gherkin as a communication tool, describing interactions with a system from multiple perspectives (or actors), and it just so happens that you can integrate it with test frameworks, which aids in ensuring that the system in place correctly handles those interactions.

Most commonly, this is from a users perspective:

```
Given John has logged in
When he receives a message from Brenda
Then he should be able to click through to his message thread with Brenda via the notification
```

But it can also be from a component/pages perspective too:

```
Given the customer history table is displayed
And there have been changes to the customer table for that user since the page was first loaded
When it receives a click to refresh the data
Then the new changes should be displayed
```

It's all about describing the behaviours, and allowing the business and developers to collaborate freely, while breaking down the language barriers that usually end up plaguing communication, and generally making both sides frustrated at each other because of a lack of mutual understanding of an issue

#### *This is where the "fun" begins* <sub>- Anakin, Ep III</sub>

You could use these files to create an environment of "living documentation" throughout your development team (and if successful, the wider business), and in theory - worded and displayed correctly, it would be an incredible boon for customer service workers, who would more easily be able to keep up with changes, and would have extremely well described help documentation - without any real additional effort, but this isn't something that I've seen much in the wild. I've written a script at work that does this by converting the features into markdown, and alongside various other markdown tools (`mermaid` for graphs, `tsdoc-plugin-markdown` to generate the API docs, and various extensions for my chosen HTML converter, `docsify`) I've managed to generate something that isn't hard to navigate and open up communication between teams that previously found it harder to communicate their issues to the dev team (most people know a little markdown these days, even if it has to be described as *"the characters you type in reddit threads and youtube comments to make text bold and italics, etc"* for people to get what it is, but it means everyone can contribute to it)

It is an extremely useful tool when it comes to debugging tests, especially when used with the screenplay pattern (less so with the standard page object model, because of the lack of additional context that the pom provides, but it's still useful), as everything is described in a way that breeds replication of the issue from a users or components perspective if it fails.

I've paired it with flow charts, where I draw out the user interactions, pinning the features to it and being able to see in a more visual way where users will be able to do something that we might not have planned for, or even figure out some garish scenario that we somehow missed.

### The Long Version Longer

My examples here will mostly in javascript, as we've been developing in a `node` environment, but if you wanted to create your own versions, it shouldn't be too different.

#### The Docs

Essentially, this is bit is just for displaying the feature files in a way that is easily digestible by the business (I have plans to integrate test reports into this too, and give the ability to switch branches and such)

[image: A look at the formatting of the gherkin]

First, you want to get a simple array of all of the files in your features folder, and pick out the ones with ".feature" on the end.

Essentially, you just need to flatten an `ls` here (this can be improved, but we have a requirement to use the LTS version of node, rather than the latest version in general)

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const walkSync = (d) => fs.statSync(d).isDirectory() ? fs.readdirSync(d).map(f => walkSync(path.join(d, f))) : d;

const flatten = (arr, result = []) => {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)){
    return [...result, arr];
  }
  arr.forEach((a) => {
    result = flatten(a, result)
  })
  return result
}

function features (folder) {
  const allFiles = flatten(walkSync(path.relative(process.cwd(), folder)))
  let convertible = []
  for (let file of allFiles) {
    if (file.match(/.feature$/)) {
      convertible.push(file)
    }
  }
  return convertible
}

...
```

Going through all of those files with a Gherkin parser to pull out your scenarios requires some set up, although it's pretty simple to do, as Gherkin has an extremely well defined structure and known keywords.

There can be a lot of self referencing, as when you boil it down to the basics, a lot of cucumber is built on well defined components. For example, you could describe a scenario as a background that can have a description, tags and a name:

```js
class Convert {

   ...

   static background (background) {
    return {
      cuke: `${background.keyword.trim()}:`,
      steps: this.steps(background.steps),
      location: this.location(background.location),
      keyword: background.keyword
    }
  }

  static scenario (scenario) {
    return {
      ...this.background(scenario),
      tags: this.tags(scenario.tags),
      cuke: `${scenario.keyword.trim()}: ${scenario.name}\n`,
      description: `${scenario.description.replace(/(?!^\s+[>].*$)(^.*$)/gm, "$1<br>").trim()}`,
      examples: this.examples(scenario.examples)
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

You can flesh it out fully to write to either a single file, or output a few markdown files (making sure to reference them in a menu file)

#### Flowcharts

Flow charts make it easier to help visualise an issue, and there are a few tools that use markdown to help generate them like this:

[image: The generated flow chart, with interactive buttons for quickly clicking through to the user journey we are interested in]

In the back, it'll end up looking like this:

````
### Login

Customers should be able to log into their account, as long as they have registered.

...


```mermaid
 graph TD
        navigateToLogin["Navigate to Login"] -->logIn{"Login"}
        logIn -->validCredentials["Valid<br>Credentials"]
        logIn -->invalidCredentials{"Invalid<br>Credentials"}
        invalidCredentials -->blankPass["Blank Password"]
        invalidCredentials -->wrongPass["Wrong Password"]
        invalidCredentials -->blankEmail["Blank Email"]
        invalidCredentials -->wrongEmail["Wrong Email"]
        ...

        click blankPass "/#/areas/login/scenario-blank-password" "View Scenario"
        ...
 ```
````

It's essentially just a really quick way to visualise issues, and links us to the correct places in the documentation to find an answer. The tool draws out the flowchart, you just have to make the connections between key concepts or ideas on the page (i.e. a new customer gets a different start screen)

#### Screenplay Pattern, Serenity and Debugging

I think all that really needs to be said here is that when you run a test, this is your output:

```
✓ Correct information on the billing page
    ✓ Given Valerie has logged into her account
        ✓ Valerie attempts to log in
            ✓ Valerie visits the login page
                ✓ Valerie navigates to '/login'
            ✓ Valerie waits up to 5s until the email field does become visible
            ✓ Valerie enters 'thisisclearlyafakeemail@somemailprovider.com' into the email field
            ✓ Valerie enters 'P@ssword!231' into the password field
            ✓ Valerie clicks on the login button
            ✓ Valerie waits for 1s
```

It will break down any part of the test into descriptions, which means if the CSS changes, we won't be searching for something that no longer exists, and even someone new to debugging that area of the site will be able to pick up from a test failure.

#### Communication

I think all of that should show how communication can be improved in a more general sense. It's all about making sure that the projects are accessible to as many people who could input something valuable (which should be everyone in your business)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But, there's things to discuss. Regarding "Use it as a springboard for communication", I think this is specific *to the Gherkin language*, but not to the tool.

Comment: Could you provide some examples regarding the usage of the tool (CLI) for: 1. debugging tests, 2. generating living documentation, 3. generating flowcharts, 4. communication.

Comment: @Kais Most certainly, the thing that Cucumber allows for is the upkeep of this gherkin documentation during the testing process, without much extra effort from the test team. The reason I suggest that it's a springboard is the fact that if you're using a Cucumber framework, the gherkin is in the right place to be a communication catalyst from the start, and the development team can easily make it visible.

I'll update my answer to cover your other 4 points there.

Comment: @Kais I've added a decent chunk there for you

Comment: I'm considering re-writing the tool in my spare time and releasing it open-source

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I understood what you wrote in 'The Docs' section. Now, how you get Cucumber to execute the script you described. Shall the script be invoked by code implementing a step definition?

Comment: I usually run the docs stuff separately, just through a script in my package.json and using node. `node ./gherkin-md/src/main.js` is what we use to generate the gherkin markdown, but the actual `docs:update` script is a lot longer, because of the smaller components, like the menu and the fact that we include API docs

Comment: I see. I asked about the Cucumber CLI involvement in the process. Now I understand that the tool *indirectly* supports the 3 points (Communication + Docs + Flowcharts) you mentioned throughout the specs written in Gherkin language.

Comment: Can we admit that Gherkin is the communication tool? and what the real tool (the Cucumber program/CLI) was called is just a POV?

Comment: I personally think, after this discussion, that Gherkin is the communication tool, and Cucumber is the QA utility.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Ah, I see! You should actually be able to link in reporters and similar functionality to cucumber and use it with the native cucumber CLI. I'll have a look into it, but essentially all this is, is a report formatter.

Gherkin is the communication tool, and the cucumber jvm, ruby and js libraries were some the first to show strength in developing a framework to utilise that tool

Comment: Here's the documentation of the [use of the cucumber CLI in general](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md)

Comment: .. And the JS implementation of Cucumber describes itself as "a tool for running automated tests written in plain language". I think we reached the point here, Cucumber is a test runner based on Gherkin. Gherkin is a ubiquitous language, used as a formal communication tool for BDD.

Comment: So I get the point here - Cucumber (CLI) *is* a testing tool. right?

Comment: That sums it up really concisely!

Comment: Many thanks Kyle for your clarifications. This is really appreciated!

Comment: Can I edit your answer to add a clarification to the ambiguity related to the definition of Cucumber?

Comment: Keeping with cucumber’s spirits, anything to make the documentation better